# Git: Why after checkout to old branch, newer commit disappeared?

Tags: git

I have made some changes to a file and commit them. Then I checkout to an older branch.

After that I find all the changes I have made disappears and the commit I made also disappears.

How can I find all the changes I made?

---

**EDIT**

This is copied from my terminal history:

```
$ git commit -m 'done clean FNAG Yishu'
[detached HEAD 8a67a04] done clean FNAG Yishu
 3 files changed, 1121 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 data/data_afterClean/amazon_Revised.txt
 create mode 100644 data/data_afterClean/epinions_Revised.txt
 create mode 100644 data/data_afterClean/slideshare_Revised.txt
```

But error happens when I try to `push`:

```
$ git push
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the current behavior after the default changes, use:

  git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

  git config --global push.default simple

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

To https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. If you did not intend to push that branch, you may want to
hint: specify branches to push or set the 'push.default' configuration variable
hint: to 'simple', 'current' or 'upstream' to push only the current branch.
```

Comment: Hold on. What makes you think the commit disappeared?

Comment: Are you sure you made that commit on the branch you think you did?

Comment: If you did not merge the branch with the newer changes into the older branch they'll not visible until you switch back to the branch with the newer changes...

Comment: Can you show the git commands you executed?

Comment: @larsmans the `checkout` command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've committed to a detached head instead of to a branch. You can get back to the commit by using its SHA-1, listed in the `git commit` output:

```
git checkout 8a67a04
```

If you want to keep this commit on a branch, create on after the checkout:

```
git checkout -b <branchname>
```

Answer (score 2):

The commit is recorded as the new tip of the branch you were on when you committed, so you can switch back by checking out that branch.

The log always shows the history of the branch you are currently on; as checkout switches branches, you are no longer on the branch you made the commit on, so it is no longer shown.

Comment: How can I do that if that branch don't have a name? I just pulled something new from the server, altered them and commit.

Comment: In that case, no branch points to the commit, so it is discarded on the next `git gc`. The *reflog* may still have a pointer, and `git fsck` would report an unconnected commit object. Note that it is normal to have unconnected commits, these are left over from rebases.

Comment: `git reflog` is what helped